# maven JaCoCo for site phase only

Tags: maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have JaCoCo working in our POM and it runs and reports every time we run `clean install`.

What we would really like to do is only run JaCoCo when a maven `site` is run.

I have tried adding:

```
...
<configuration>
<skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
....
```

And setting `jacoco.skip` to `true` for the build phase, but in the reporting section, I have added:

```
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>   
<configuration>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
...
```

But this does not work. Setting `jacoco.skip` to `true` does prevent JaCoCo running on normal maven clean install's but also appears to affect the reporting.

**Question**: How would I configure maven so that JaCoCo runs successfully for a maven site, but does not run for a `mvn clean install`?

Comment: can you share a bit more of the jacoco plugin configuration of your POM? How are you running jacoco? only via command line or is there any execution configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to delegate it to a Maven [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), removing its configuration for your `build` section and placing it into a profile as following:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jacoco</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
                    <configuration><!-- here --></configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can then add your custom configuration there.

Then normal builds will not apply it, while you could always activate it via:

```
mvn clean install -Pjacoco
```

or

```
mvn site -Pjacoco
```

Comment: Thanks. Using maven to do what maven does. Good answer. I added an activation block that would activate this profile by default on our Jenkins server too so that the reports are available in Jenkins but local builds that only want a swift build have JaCoCo disabled.